# LIKE with % JOIN in AWS Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am trying to left join Column A with Column B using a LIKE % but did not seem to get anything working until now

```
Column A
TPO1-Dest
HJUE-Main
Flight-JKO1

Column B
TPO1
Main
JKO1

Expected Output
TPO1-Dest            TPO1
HJUE-Main            Main
Flight-JKO1          JKO1
```

Comment: Do you mean `Table A` and `Table B`? Or are you really trying to `JOIN` two columns within the same table? Please show us the code you tried.

Answer (score 0):

If they are actually two separate tables, you could use:

```sql
SELECT
  tableA.a,
  tableB.b
FROM tableA, tableB
WHERE tableA.a LIKE '%' | tableB.b | '%'
```